# 1)Reserved 2)Nonce 3)Congestion Window Reduced CWR are setting 1 in packet recieved from Raw socket Server

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, raw-sockets

I am having raw socket server but when it respond to client I am getting following flags set

1. Reserved
2. Nonce
3. Congestion Window Reduced CWR

I believe it Nonce flag has to do with checksum. For tcp checksum I viewed from other sources that checksum
]does not include flags and some other fields and I am creating checksum on every field before calculating
checksum by just passing entire tcphdr pointer to memory to checksum function before checksum. If that's the
reason or any other reason of having these flags to be set to 1 then please explain

Also what these flags are for also please explain

Comment: Nonce and CWR are related to Explicit Congestion Notification (ECN).  It is not clear to me if you are saying that you are sending these or receiving them.  If you are receiving a SYN with ECN flags set, it is indicating a willingness to use ECN.

Comment: @JimD. i am sending it from server with syn 1 and checking it on client side using wireshark. I did not set ECN flags. what ECN flags are named as in tcphdr?

Comment: Bits 6,7, and 8 (0 indexed) in the TCP header flags are used for ECN.  Bit 8 is the nonce sum, 7 is CWR, and 6 is ECE.  https://www.iana.org/assignments/tcp-header-flags/tcp-header-flags.xml#tcp-header-flags-1

Comment: Note that if you did not set the ECN bits and some intermediate device set them, the received TCP checksum should differ from the original checksum you calculated.